# Python: Subarrays into One Array -> Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[[32794.211244][32570.179709][32710.191036]] -> [32794.211244, 32570.179709, 32710.191036]

I am trying to convert these subarrays to one array using numpy.

Comment: Maybe just [`flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) or [`ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel)?

Comment: Describe these "subarrays" in more detail.  First is this an array or list?  If array, what is the `shape` and `dtype`?  If list, what's the `len` and character of the element(s).  `array with subarrays` is a vague description.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have just to reshape if your vector is already a numpy array. So if your vector has a dimension (3,1) like in your example:

```
t = [[32794.211244],[32570.179709],[32710.191036]]
np.reshape(t, (3,))

give you:
array([32794.211244, 32570.179709, 32710.191036])
```